# Azure serverless signalR - if Receiver is not available

Tags: signalr, azure-functions, serverless

I am using Azure serverless signalR with Azure functions to broadcast messages to the single and multiple users. I have a question, if receiver is not connected to signalR, 
1) Is Azure signalR helps in storing those messages and redeliver when receiver is available..??
2) I am using the UserId during negotiation with the azure function signalR , while message sending can it be possible to see who are connected to Azure serverless signalR in azure function.

could anyone please help in answer above questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is Azure signalR helps in storing those messages and redeliver when receiver is available..??

This is not possible and by design for SignalR Service. This is stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-internals#data-transmit-between-client-and-server) as well.

You would have to implement this separately.

> 2. I am using the UserId during negotiation with the azure function signalR , while message sending can it be possible to see who are connected to Azure serverless signalR in azure function.

While the Azure SignalR Service maps users and connections internally, there is no way to query this information. **But** [the service raises events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-event-grid-integration#available-azure-signalr-service-events) which you can use to create your own mapping that you can use in your application.